# How to extract a selection of text from a text node using Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hi I'm trying to pull part of a sentence from text within a node

```
The xml:

    <coast>
<area>
Forecast for coasts from Malin Head to Howth Head to Roches Point and the Irish Sea
</area>
<wind>Northwest force 6 to gale force 8 and gusty, decreasing force 5 to 7 this morning. Increasing early tonight northwest force 7 to gale force 8.</wind>
</coast>
<all-wx><head>Weather for all sea areas:</head>
<text>
 Scattered showers, some will be wintry.</text>
</all-wx>
<all-vis><head>Visibility for all sea areas:</head>
<text>
 Poor in any showers.Warning of heavy swell: along Atlantic coasts.</text>
</all-vis>
<outlook time="0600" day="Sunday" date="01 February 2015">
<head>Outlook for a further 24 hours until 0600 Sunday 01 February 2015: </head>
<text> Gale force to strong gale force northerly winds with further showers, some will be thundery.</text>
</outlook>
<gale-text>
Northwest winds will reach gale force for a time this morning on all Irish coastal waters and on the Irish Sea  </gale-text>
<craft-text>
NIL  </craft-text>

The xsl:

     <xsl:template match="coast">
                <p>
                    <h4><xsl:value-of select="area"/></h4>
                    <p><strong>Wind: </strong>
                        <xsl:value-of select="wind"/>
                    </p>
                        <xsl:if test="weather">
                            <p>
                                <strong>Weather: </strong>
                                <xsl:value-of select="weather"/>
                            </p>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="visibility">
                            <p>
                                <strong>Visibility: </strong>
                                <xsl:value-of select="visibility"/>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <xsl:template match="text">
                                      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'Warning of heavy swell:')"/>
                                </xsl:template>
                            </p>
                        </xsl:if>
                </p>
            </xsl:template>
```

I wish to extract the text to the right of Warning of heavy swell: and display on web page

Above doesn't work.

Very newbie coder - any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'Warning of heavy swell:')"/>
<xsl:template>
```

then you get the string following `Warning of heavy swell:` in the `text` element.

Comment: Hi Thanks,It's not working for me but I think this is because I didn't put the complete section of code in the clip. I have added it in now

Comment: A `template` is a top level element, so you have to put it as a child of the `xsl:stylesheet`, you can't nest templates. To make sure an element is processed by a matching template you make sure `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is done in the template of an ancestor or of the parent.

Comment: And after your edit I don't see `Warning of heavy swell` anymore in your input sample so I am not sure why your question is to take text after that string.

Comment: Hi, the text under all-vis has Warning of heavy swell: along Atlantic coasts.

Comment: Basically I need to place this on a html page with Warning of heavy swell in bolder text and whatever text comes in after the semi colon beside it . the xml file comes in from a feed that updates three times a day and the text after warning of a heavy swell will change as weather does. I know I haven't structured the xsl correctly